# Does NSUndoManager retain its arguments?

Tags: cocoa, memory-management, nsundomanager

The following is code for enabling undo from the book cocoa programming for OS X by Aaron Hillegas :

```
-(void)removeObjectFromEmployeesAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
Person *p = [employees objectAtIndex:index];
NSLog(@"removing %@ from %@", p, employees);
// Add the inverse of this operation to the undo stack 
NSUndoManager *undo = [self undoManager]; [[undo prepareWithInvocationTarget:self]  insertObject:p inEmployeesAtIndex:index]; 

if (![undo isUndoing]) { 
  [undo setActionName:@"Remove Person"];
} 
[employees removeObjectAtIndex:index];
}
```

While removing an employee , we push a command onto the undo stack to reinsert that employee  into the array . But what guarantee is there that p wont have been released when the undo is invoked ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'p' will get retained when the NSInvocation is created by "[[undo prepareWithInvocationTarget:self]  insertObject:p inEmployeesAtIndex:index]"

Comment: This is true . I tried NSLogging the retain counts . But where is it documented ? It isnt there in the NSUndoManager or prepareWithInvocationTarget documentation.

Comment: It's not explicitly documented but assumed based on the general rules for memory mgt. using reference counts.  In this case, if an object (the NSInvocation) wants to keep a reference to an object it needs to retain it.  The caller doesn't care and can release the object once it's done with it--no different, e.g., as in adding an object to an NSArray.  [NSArray addObject:] is responsible for retaining the added object.  The caller can immediately release it when [NSArray addObject:] returns.

Comment: The documentation for NSInvocation explicitly states that it does not retain any of the objects unless the caller sends a retainObjects message. In my opinion this is a documentation fail.

Comment: Apparently it's not the NSInvocation that is retaining the arguments but rather the proxy returned by [NSUndoManager prepareWithInvocationTarget:].