# How to force NSUndoManager prepareWithInvocationTarget to retain it's arguments?

Tags: ios, nsundomanager, nsinvocation

NSUndoManager method prepareWithInvocationTarget **does not retain arguments**. There is no links to this in Apple docs, but I've checked with profiler, and I'm pretty sure - it does not. This means if you are going to delete an object and be prepared for undo - you should retain it yourself (like assign it to some *trash array* and remove the original link). Those kind of *fake removes* creates a lot of unnecessary fuss, especially when you need to get rid of the old undos.

However, NSInvocation **can retain arguments** by calling retainArguments method. Since NSUndoManager uses NSInvocation for prepareWithInvocationTarget it might be the way to pass retainArguments to NSUndoManager.

The question is - how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's right there in the [**Undo Architecture**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/UndoArchitecture/Articles/CleaningUndoStack.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000208-BBCBFHGJ) guide:

> An NSUndoManager object does not retain the targets of undo
>   operations. The client—the object performing undo operations—typically
>   owns the undo manager, so if the undo manager in turn retained its
>   target this would frequently create a retain cycle.

So **No**, it doesn't - for the reasons given in the docs.

You'll have to manage live cycles on your own. How entirely depends on and is completely specific to your apps model.. I guess the general question boils down to:

**How do we know when the NSUndoManager will 'pop' an action from the undo stack (so we can safely delete our context data we're keeping around for the undo operation).**

Unfortunately there's no (documented) notification in the [NSUndoManager Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUndoManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSUndoManager) that's sent e.g. when `removeAllActionsWithTarget:` is invoked on an undo manager instance.

Almost seems like there's no real alternative to keep that additional information around forever (or manually [limit the levels of undo](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUndoManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUndoManager/setLevelsOfUndo%3a) and adjust the storage for the undo context data accordingly).

Comment: I think the intent of the question was to figure out how to retain the NSInvocation arguments, not the target.  You're correct about the retain cycle for a target, but I don't see how retaining the arguments would create a cycle.

Answer (score 0):

While the answer that was given is correct with respect to the target, the answer with respect to the arguments is: There's no need to retain them, because the undo manager does it. See [Does NSUndoManager retain its arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12758069/does-nsundomanager-retain-its-arguments)